# Celery's expires option doesn't work

Tags: python, celery

I'm playing around with Celery, and I'm trying to do a periodic task with `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER`. Here is my configuration:

```
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Kiev'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'run-task-every-5-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.run_every_five_seconds',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
        'options': {
            'expires': 10,
        }
    },
}

# the task
@app.task()
def run_every_five_seconds():
   return '5 seconds passed'
```

When running the beat with `celery -A celery_app beat` the task doesn't seem to expire. Then I've read that there might be some issue with the beat, so it do not take into account the expires option.

Then I've tried to do a task, so it gets called manually.

```
@app.task()
def print_hello():
    while True:
        print datetime.datetime.now()
        sleep(1)
```

I am calling the task in this way:

```
print_hello.apply_async(args=[], expires=5)
```

The worker's console is telling my that my task will expire, but it doesn't get expired as well. It's getting executed infinitely.

```
Received task: tasks.print_hello[05ee0175-cf3a-492b-9601-1450eaaf8ef7] expires:[2016-01-15 00:08:03.707062+02:00]
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 13):

I think you have understood the `expires` argument wrong.

The documentation says: "The task will not be executed after the expiration time." [ref](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async). It means the execution will not start if the expiration time has passed. If the execution has already started, the execution will run to completion.

Your configuration adds a task to task queue every 5 seconds. If the execution does not start in 10 seconds from the time the task is added to the task queue, the task is discarded. However, the tasks is executed immediately because there is a free celery worker available.

Your code example adds a task that is discarded if the execution is not started in 5 seconds.

To get the functionality you want, you can replace `'expires': 10,` with `'expires': datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=10),`. That will set the `expires` to a absolute time.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the previous answer, the purpose of the expire parameter is captured at: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/591

**Let me explain with an example,**

let's say you are scheduling a task to be executed every 5 minutes.  so celery beat adds the task every 5 minutes to the task queue.   Now, for some reason if the worker was not working, it would not pick any task from the task queue.  The task queue grows over time with many repetitive tasks.  As soon as the worker starts, it has a huge backlog and wastes time in doing the old tasks.

**Solution?**  `expires` parameter.

Each task now will have, let's say 1 minute of expiring time. So when the worker is online again, it discards all old tasks which are expires and only works on the latest unexpired task. Thanks to this, worker doesn't have to waste time in old repetitive tasks.

**Best Practice**

When you don't know what to set the expires time, it's always good to set it equal to the schedule/interval.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers only seem to apply to celery and not celery beat.

The correct way to do that using celery beat is to use the `expire_seconds` option, as the `expires` option only accepts a datetime :

```py
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'run-task-every-5-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.run_every_five_seconds',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
        'options': {
            'expire_seconds': 10,
        }
    },
}
```

This is not very clear in the celery beat documentation but it is [mentioned
here](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/django_celery_beat/models.html#:%7E:text=expire_seconds).